# Bind Listbox items from library datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, types, datatemplate

Application is WPF .netframework

I need to bind properties as itemsource to listbox from class which is in .dll. There is the main problem because if I Bind some other Collection which doesn't have Model in dll. it works, but I need to have it in library.

xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MessageLibrary;assembly=MessageLibrary"

I don't know how to fix it, I tried almost everything

I looked at MSDN and there was the exactly same example a nothing work. I'll be very thankful to somebody solve this please

Here is the ItemSourceCollection in MainViewModel

```
 public ObservableCollection<ViewModelUser> AllUsers { get; set; }
 public ObservableCollection<ViewModelRoom> AllRooms { get; set; }
 AllUsers = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelUser>();
 AllRooms = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelUser>();
```

Here is my xaml class:

```
<Window x:Class="ChatsUPClient.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChatsUPClient"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ChatsUPClient.ViewModel"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MessageLibrary;assembly=MessageLibrary"
    Title="ChatsUP" Height="600" Width="900">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="UserNameTextBlock" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=LRName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="MessageTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Path=Input, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="MessageTimeLine" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Output}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Typewriter"/>
    <Button x:Name="SendBtn" Content="Odeslat" Grid.Column="3"  Grid.Row="3" Command="{Binding Path=ProcessCommand}"/>
    <Button x:Name="CreateRoomBtn" Content="Vytvořit místnost"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="CreateRoomName" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.505,0.438">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"   ItemsSource="{Binding AllRooms}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type c:ViewModelUser}">
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path= NameOfconversation}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
        <ListBox   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding AllUsers}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type c:ViewModelUser}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding  NickName}"> </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Entry" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Vstoupit"></Button>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="LoginPanel">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Enter Name and Password</TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=LRName}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="PasswordTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=LRPassword}"/>
        <Button Content="Přihlásit se/Registrovat" Command="{Binding Path=LogingCommand}" Click="OnSave" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

class in library looks like this:

```
public class ViewModelUser
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: There is a public AllUsers property in MainViewModel, which is a collection of ViewModelUser? As a note, when you assign a DataTemplate to the ItemTemplate property of an ItemsControl, you don't need to set its DataType property. The type is implicit, i.e. the ItemsSource element type.

Comment: What you have provided looks fine.  So the problem is most like in what you haven't provided.  Where is the MainViewModel?  Look in the output window.  Binding errors will be reported there.